# Undo posmap and posconf commands

Tags: command-line, email, postfix

Attempting to enhance my postfix header signature, I've run these commands on my Ubuntu server:

```
sudo postmap header_checks
sudo postconf -e 'smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks'
```

with parameters on the `header_checks` file, but since then my spf doesn't work!

I want to undo these commands. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

To undo these configuration changes you should simply remove the line with `smtp_header_checks` from you `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file and reload postfix service (`service postfix reload`).